# How to wait for Rails service response before continuing controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cloudinary

I've read several articles and S.O. posts but just seem to be getting even more confused.

I have a Vue app with a Rails API, and am trying to allow for the user to upload a profile avatar. On the front end I'm using [Uppload](https://github.com/elninotech/uppload) which sends a POST to my Rails endpoint. In the controller action I'm using the [Cloudinary gem](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration) to perform the upload.

Basically what I'm looking to do is perform the Cloudinary upload, then use the url from the response to update that field in my database.

*profiles_controller.rb*

```
def update_avatar
  res = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:file], folder: 'avatars')
  current_user.update(avatar_url: res[:secure_url])
  @user = current_user
end
```

Of course `res[:secure_url]` returns empty because the response hasn't returned yet, but how do I wait for the response before trying to update the field for my `current_user`?

Comment: I would consider sending the image directly from the client to Cloudinary and then just send a patch request to your rails controller with ajax when the image is uploaded. This will avoid tying up your web threads. https://cloudinary.com/documentation/vue_integration

Comment: Ahh that's an interesting thought. I think you're right, I'm gonna go that route. Thanks!